# The use of hyphen in consecutive compounds

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compounds, periods, titles

I am not that punctuation-savy, so I have one question for my research title.

Currently it is

> Social crowdfunding:  individual- and project-related determinants of success.    Empirical investigation on Kickstarter

Here I have two questions.

1. Is it right to say individual- or just individual?
2. Should there be a period after "Empirical investigation on Kickstarter"?

Comment: "-" is not a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) to begin with. It's a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen).

Comment: @RegDwighт, already mentioned that in my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Both questions have quite an easy answer: it depends on the style guide you have to adhere to for your research (it’s unclear whether it’s an article, a thesis, for a book, or something entirely different).

#### Individual(-) and project-related

Your first question is about what is known as a *suspension hyphen* (or sometimes a *suspended hyphen*), which indicates that the word it ends is the left base of a compound whose right base has been omitted, usually to avoid repetition. (Note: it’s a hyphen, not a dash.)

Suspension hyphens are very commonly used and not often left out in formal writing, and I would guess that most style guides would advise you to use them when appropriate—especially since leaving them out can make the sentence ambiguous: are we talking about both project-related and individual determinants, or about determinants related to both projects and individual?

The [Chicago Manual of Style (5.91.4)](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec091.html) says:

> If two phrasal adjectives end in a common element, the ending element should appear only with the second phrase, and a suspension hyphen should follow the unattached words to show that they are related to the ending element: *middle- and upper-class operagoers*. But if two phrasal adjectives begin with a common element, a hyphen is usually inappropriate, and the element should be repeated: *left-handed and left-brained executives*.

– but you should of course follow the advice of whatever style guide you have to adhere to.

#### To dot or not to dot

Your second question is really more one of layout and (graphic) styling. If your title will appear on a front page in fancy lettering, the dot can be included or omitted based purely on aesthetic grounds.

If it is going to be a ‘regular’ heading (for example the heading of an article in a journal), you should look at other similar articles in the journal to see what the accepted practice is. I doubt many style guides include this in their scope, and it is usually left up to the individual journal/series/monograpy/anthology editor(s) how they wish to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you for citing a recommendation of CMoS I actually like.

Comment: Incidentally, OP's particular case is one of semantics, not style.

Answer (score 0):

> individual and project related determinants

or

> individual and project-related determinants  --> better

Do **not** use a hyphen with 'individual': that would mean "individual-related" & "project-related". There are no consecutive compounds in the example.

The use of hyphen in "project related" is optional because the phrase is well-recognized and will cause no problems without a hyphen.

You can use an *n*-dash and an indefinite article. It's still an expression, not a sentence, so no period.

> Social crowdfunding: individual- and project-related determinants of success – An empirical investigation on Kickstarter

Comment: If your hypothesis that there are no consecutive compounds in the example is correct, then you would of course be right. I would not be so fast to rule that out, though—I don’t see why determinants to social crowdfunding success could not be individual-related as well as project-related without reading the thesis in question.

Comment: I think that it might be hard to say whether it would be "individual-related" or just "individual" determinants.  If the former, then the hyphen is called for, but if the latter it is not.  I am not sure what it even means to be individual-related, but project-related doesn't seem to suffer from this.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, since this thesis is about Kickstarter, it makes perfect sense to me to speak of success determinants as being either project-related (i.e., specific to the project that obtains success) or individual-related (i.e., based on the individual who created the project, more than the project itself). Some Kickstarters kind of become synonymous with success, so when they start a new project, it almost automatically does well, regardless of what it is; that would be an individual-related determinant of success.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In any case, my answer has the answers to both the possibilities: *that would mean "individual-related" & "project-related"*. I was aware my reading of the sentence and presumption of the context may not be right, but the answers are there, right?